# Gradle dagger lint: ignore by package

Tags: android, gradle, dagger

I've created an Android project using Gradle. I've added a Dagger library:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
}
```

After trying to compile the project I get a build failure due to lint exceptions:

```
InvalidPackage: Package not included in Android
```

> ../../../../../../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.dagger/dagger-compiler/1.2.1/c8bf6c2fda9b27f4d44a2aa4280df525a1408771/dagger-compiler-1.2.1.jar:
>   Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android:
>   javax.annotation.processing. Referenced from
>   dagger.internal.codegen.GraphAnalysisErrorHandler.
>
> ../../../../../../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.dagger/dagger-compiler/1.2.1/c8bf6c2fda9b27f4d44a2aa4280df525a1408771/dagger-compiler-1.2.1.jar:
>   Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android:
>   javax.lang.model.type. Referenced from
>   dagger.internal.codegen.GeneratorKeys.
>
> ../../../../../../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.dagger/dagger-compiler/1.2.1/c8bf6c2fda9b27f4d44a2aa4280df525a1408771/dagger-compiler-1.2.1.jar:
>   Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android:
>   javax.lang.model.util. Referenced from
>   dagger.internal.codegen.GraphAnalysisErrorHandler.
>
> ../../../../../../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup/javawriter/2.3.0/4b290e394ea3109be5c0b7f08ff75de089125122/javawriter-2.3.0.jar:
>   Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android:
>   javax.lang.model.element. Referenced from
>   com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter.

So, I have to either fix or make lint ignore Dagger packages. I've setup `lint.xml` but I can't figure out a way to ignore:

```
 <issue id="InvalidPackage">
  <ignore ...INSERT DECLARATION TO IGNORE DAGGER PACKAGE... />
 </issue>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Found the answer here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/e6a5b9c7c1bca4da402de442315b5ff1ada819c7

adding in build.gradle in android section, lintOptions solved the issue for me:

```
android {
...

   lintOptions {
       disable 'InvalidPackage'
   }
}
```

adding the same ignore statement in lint.xml did not worked for me.

Comment: This will disable the invalid package for your entire build - would be very nice to only ignore it for a specific dependency, to ensure you get the warning when you import a new lib!

Comment: You can do this that way : `lintOptions {
   warning 'InvalidPackage'
}` It will pass the InvalidPackage as a warning instead of an error without disabling lint

Comment: Why does lint do this in the first place? People need to include proprietary jar files in their apps. Can anyone explain to me why lint marks this as an issue?

Comment: @deive Did you find how to disable it only for specific package?

Comment: @Dr.jacky unfortunately, I haven't.

Comment: @Dr.jacky look the answer below

Answer (score 5):

FYI, as of version 0.10.1 of the Android Gradle plugin this will no longer be necessary; lint will automatically ignore these issues found within Dagger:
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/93140/

Comment: This is nice for Dagger, but won't help those who have this issue with less common libraries.

Comment: As of Dagger 2.8 and Gradle 2.2 it seems this is still a problem.

Comment: Yes, with Dagger 2.9 this is still happening

Answer (score 0):

You can add a regexp to `lint.xml` that matches any file in the package:

```
<lint>
  <issue id="InvalidPackage">
    <ignore regexp=".*\.gradle.*" />
  </issue>
</lint>
```