# itext for android and lint error

Tags: android, gradle, itext, lint

I add itext for android library for android to my project, everything works but when I build my project using gradle lint generate this error:

```
InvalidPackage: Package not included in Android
../../libs/itextg-5.5.3.jar: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: java.awt. Referenced from com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BarcodeCodabar.
../../libs/itextg-5.5.3.jar: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: java.awt.image. Referenced from com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BarcodeCodabar.
../../libs/itextg-5.5.3.jar: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.management. Referenced from com.itextpdf.testutils.ITextTest.
../../libs/itextg-5.5.3.jar: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.xml.crypto.dom. Referenced from com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature.
../../libs/itextg-5.5.3.jar: Invalid package reference in library; not included in Android: javax.xml.crypto.dsig. Referenced from com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeXmlSignature.
```

Is it secure to suppress and ignore this error ?

I downloaded the latest android itext versione (5.5.3)

Thanks

Comment: have you used android studio ? check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827004/gradle-dagger-lint-ignore-by-package

Comment: I'm not aware of any free iText library for Android. However, there is a commercial iText library for Android, you can find some info [here](http://itextpdf.com/pricing/android_license). Unfortunately, if you decide to go with it, it will set you back [quite] a few bucks.

Answer (score 5):

Those dependencies were accidentally left in the android port of 5.5.3.

They will be removed for the upcoming 5.5.4 (release is in two weeks).

Comment: I tried the new release but I still get the same error:Explanation: Finds API accesses to APIs that are not supported in Android.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend upon whether you need any of those classes, directly or indirectly. Using `BarcodeCodabar`, `ITextTest`, or `MakeXmlSignature` will likely result in a `VerifyError` at runtime, when those classes try using Java SE classes that do not exist in Android.

You might consider seeing if there is an Android-specific distribution of this library.

Answer (score 0):

> You might consider seeing if there is an Android-specific distribution of this library.

Actually I use the Android version of the library, this means that they simply do not remove the reference even if these classes are not actually used? My app perfectly works !

@HareshChhelana

Thansks I use the gradle Lint option to suppress the worning